# Constant lengths (dimensional constants) and scaling

Tags: calculus, geometry, transformation, constants

Suppose in the $xy$-plane we have defined the constant length $L$. This can be a fixed radius of a circle; or a boundary condition or any condition such, that $L$ has dimension of "meters" and is constant.

Now, scale the plane 
$$x'=Cx$$
$$y'=Cy$$

Does this mean that in the new, primed coordinates, $L'=CL$? Or does $L$ stay exactly the same, $L'=L$?

I want to understand how fixed-length objects behave when the plane is scaled down (that is, when every graph of a function y=y(x) is scaled down).

It is confusing, because all variable-related objects (functions, curves, etc) in the plane must be scaled down; but $L$, being a constant, is not related to any variables, yet is defined in the plane. Does $L$ scale down also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Take a segment $AB$ of length $L$ based on coordinates of $A$ and $B$. Compute the image of $A \to A^\prime$ and $B \to B^\prime$ by the scaling. What is the length of the segment $A^\prime B^\prime$?

Comment: $L=\sqrt{(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2}$; now transform $x_i ^{\prime} = Cx_i$ and $y_i ^{\prime} = Cy_i$, where $i \in \{a,b\}$ and I get $L'=CL$. The confusion comes from "how you actually scale". Because in this example, $L$ seems not like a constant, but more like $L=L(x,y)$... A "constant" length should not be tied to the variables $x,y$, right? Where is my thinking wrong.

Comment: @user142523 $L$ is not a constant but the length is scaled by the constant of the scaling $C$.

Comment: I was thinking of $L$ as a constant term that has a value that is constant or cannot change, because it does not contain any modifiable variables.

Comment: are you referring to the units of measurement, "meter". Are you saying, because the units are scaled down, this is why the dimensional constant $L$ is scaled down too?